# On Multithreading - Method is getting invoked twice

Tags: java, multithreading

I just started learning threads and I'm trying to work on multithreads. I'm not sure why method1() is getting invoked twice. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

I've tried my best to make the example simple/ clear by removing lot of stuff

```
class A implements Runnable {

  public void method1() {
    System.out.println("Method1");
  }

  public void methodThread(int numberOfThreads) {
      List<Thread> threads = new ArrayList<Thread>();
      for(int i=0; i<numberOfThreads; i++) {
        Thread t = new Thread(this, "Thread - " +i);
        t.start();
      }

      for(int i=0; i<numberOfThreads; i++) {
        threads.get(i).join();
      }
  }

  @Override
    public void run() {
      System.out.print(Thread.currentThread().getName() + this.method1());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
      A a = new A();
      a.methodThread(1);
    }
}

Expected output:
Thread - 0 Method1

Actual output
Method1 // Called again??
Thread - 0 Method1
```

Comment: This doesn't compile -- no return type for methods `method1` or `methodThread`.

Comment: Add a breakpoint inside method1() and inspect the callstack.

Comment: I was just trying to put the sudo code :/

Comment: This still doesn't pass compilation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your method method1() does an actual output, and this occurs before the value is printed from your run method. But then it looks like you're trying to add the returned value (which perhaps in your code is "method1") to the name of the thread:

```
System.out.print(Thread.currentThread().getName() + this.method1());
```

This will cause the behaviour you're seeing.

Comment: I was printing the values again. Thanks